# Error while creating controller with read write actions and views using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an error while creating controller with read write actions and views using entity framework.

I have got an error:

> "Unable to retrive metadata for 'PHARMACY.Models.User'. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Object.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Object.ObjectContext'."

How to solve this?

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Fullname", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select User type", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "User Type")]
    public string User_Type { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Login Status", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Login Status")]
    public string Login_Status { get; set; }
}

public class UserDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a controller that use one of my models, I get this warning. This is my model.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC5 ?
Because ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later !!

You need to upgrade your visual studio to VS2013 or if you are under MVC4, change your project to target MVC5 instead.

Comment: And what is the version of your visual studio? and nuGet?